# Not be able to set up Membership Type and Payment Type

Tags: civimember

We want to build similar form as described here :https://glos.us/civicrm/profile/create?gid=15&reset=1 , into our new site here: http://manningmedia.net/glos/test/, We are not be able to show **Membership Type** and **Payment Type** fields on our new website, from where can we setup that ? to show it above the form.

Comment: Can you please add the version of CiviCRM you are using and the CMS (Wordpress, Drupal or Joomla), that will help getting an answer. I assume you have set up the Membership Types in CiviCRM as described here: http://book.civicrm.org/user/membership/defining-memberships/

Answer (score 2):

The links to the forms you've provided look like stand-alone CiviCRM Profiles.

To allow for membership registration with online payment, you need to set up a Contribution Page, which allows you to configure payment options and the types of memberships that can be selected, as well as on screen messages and email receipts. You'll include the profile you want completed in the set up as well.

The CiviCRM book explains in full detail how you can set up a Contribution page: http://book.civicrm.org/user/contributions/setup/